# Android using colors from colors.xml(@color/black) vs inline colors((#000000) in XML File Performance

Tags: android

```
<TextView
           android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

vs

```
 <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Which on is more efficient in terms of performance

Comment: neither is going to have enough of an impact on performance to justify it, there's nothing to be concerned about here. using `@color/black` allows you to reuse colors and variables, which is standard

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thankyou

Comment: Technically the second one should be faster, since the value is already there. But yeah, it makes no sense to try to optimize that, use the first one if you need to reuse values. Things like this will barely have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is negligible performance difference whether you use a color inline or define it in colors.xml

But I would suggest you define your colors in colors.xml because in doing so your code will be more readable and you can reuse colors defined in colors.xml